# Cannot send email in CakePhp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I make API for send email using cakephp. This is my code:

```
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $this->autoLayout = false;
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $title = $data['title'];
        $content = $data['content'];   
        $Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
        $Email->from('myemail@gmail.com');
        $Email->to($data['email'][0]);

        $Email->subject($title);

        $Email->send($content);
```

And it show error php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname. Please help me in this case

Comment: Please always tag questions with the version of cake you are using, and provide stack traces/context for error messages.

Comment: Yes, I will do this next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that php cannot communicate with the host `hostname` - this comes from [the configuration for that class](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html):

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $smtp = array(
        'host' => 'hostname', // <---
        ...
    );
}
```

Either it's badly configured, or the domain name does not resolve.